# How to break a collider into 2 different box colliders for a box body in andengine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics

I have a very simple sprite which is thick in the upper half and thin in the bottom half. And I have attached a box body to it. Now the problem is collisions happening even when the object didn't touch the sprite in the bottom half as the body is taken as a rectangle. What I want to do exactly is modify the collider width for the upper part and the bottom part. Can someone tell me how to do it and what is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Body's can be made up of multiple fixtures, so you can just make two fixtures, one for the upper half and one for the bottom half, and add them both to the body.

For example, if you wanted to make the bottom half a 2x4 rectangle, and the top half a 4x4 rectangle, you would do something like this:

```
    PolygonShape bottomHalfShape = new PolygonShape();
    bottomHalfShape.set(new Vector2[] {new Vector2(2, 0), new Vector2(4, 0), new Vector2(4, 4), new Vector2(2, 4)});
    PolygonShape topHalfShape = new PolygonShape();
    topHalfShape.set(new Vector2[] {new Vector2(0, 4), new Vector2(4, 4), new Vector2(4, 8), new Vector2(0, 8)});

    FixtureDef bottomHalf = new FixtureDef();
    bottomHalf.shape = bottomHalfShape;
    FixtureDef topHalf = new FixtureDef();
    topHalf.shape = topHalfShape;

    body.createFixture(bottomHalf);
    body.createFixture(topHalf);
```

Note that this is example code for libGDX, it may have to be modified slightly for AndEngine.

Comment: Don't I have to delete the shape developed by default when creating the body with this function
final Body b = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, MY_SPRITE, BodyType.KinematicBody, objectFixtureDef);

Comment: @RohitGoyal Yes, you have to destroy all shapes you create once you're done using them.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? Can't find any function which can tell me the default shape and destroy them.

Comment: @RohitGoyal My apologies, in AndEngine, it seems as though you don't have to do that.